# Drupal 7 user picture link

Tags: drupal, hyperlink, image, account

I just need the link of the profile picture of the current logged-in user in Drupal 7. I tried this:

```
global $user;
print $user->picture;
```

output: 2

And this:

```
global $user;
print  theme('user_picture', array('account' => $user));
```

Output: the image as a < img >-element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The picture is stored as a reference to a file in the `files` table, you can load the file and extract the path like this:

```
global $user;
$fid = $user->picture;

$file = file_load($fid);
$uri = $file->uri; // URI path, e.g. public://image.jpg
$path = file_create_url($uri); // Web accessible path, e.g. /sites/default/files/image.jpg
```